# How To Random Select A String From List After Tabbing Button

Tags: string, list, flutter, random

I would like to press a button and pick a random string from my list to display somewhere on the screen.

Currently, the convoTopic variable within the builder is running an error.

Any help is appreciated!

Below is my truncated code:

```
final List<String> ConvoTopics = [
'blah blah',
'black sheep',
'balh bath'
];

class ConvoPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _ConvoPageState createState() => _ConvoPageState();
}

class _ConvoPageState extends State<ConvoPage> 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void generateConvoTopic() {
      final _random = Random();
      var convoTopic = ConvoTopics[_random.nextInt(ConvoTopics.length)];
      print(convoTopic);
    }

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff04072E),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Convo', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff04072E),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(convoTopic,
                    ),
// where randomized string appears
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
            
              onPressed: () async {
                generateConvoTopic();
              },
    // button's function is to randomize convo topic
              child: Container(
                child: Text('Get Convo'),
              ),
            ),
:
:
:
```

Comment: define ```convoTopic``` in the ```_ConvoPageState``` with an initial value, and then when you generate a new ```convoTopic``` you have to call setState to rebuild the build method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is mostly correct.

Three small things you were missing were

1. You should define your `generateConvoTopic` in your `State` class rather than the `build` method.
2. Your `convoTopic` should be a `State` class variable. You are currently defining it inside a `function` inside the `build` method. So it will only be accessible inside your `function` but you need to update it and read it, so it will go in `State` class.
3. You should call `setState` whenever you want to update any variable of your `State` class. In your case, the `convoTopic` after you follow step 2.
4. List item

;

```
final List<String> ConvoTopics = ['blah blah', 'black sheep', 'balh bath']
class ConvoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ConvoPageState createState() => _ConvoPageState();
}

class _ConvoPageState extends State<ConvoPage> {
  String convoTopic;

  void generateConvoTopic() {
    setState(() {
      convoTopic = ConvoTopics[Random().nextInt(ConvoTopics.length)];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff04072E),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Convo', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff04072E),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(convoTopic),
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  generateConvoTopic();
                },
                child: Container(
                  child: Text('Get Convo'),
                ),
              ),
    ]))));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nisanth. Got it! 
Nisanth, by any chance, you know how to solve this? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67656339/attaching-index-to-list-item-string-flutter

Thanks!

Comment: Glad to have helped :). Checking the other one.

Comment: There already seems to be answer, check it out

Comment: Hi @VegetaSaiyan. Yes, I am a full stack developer but I just started learning Flutter a month ago. I used to work in React Native. But I am from India and also changed jobs just last week. So am not looking for a change as of now. But sometime in the future, maybe ? You can always connet with me at https://www.linkedin.com/in/reddynishanth/